# gem5 simulation: error when goodbye.sayGoodbye(myName) calls

Tags: c++, gem5

I am learning gem5 simulator with my little knowledge in C++ and I was following [this](http://learning.gem5.org/book/part2/parameters.html) tutorial instruction. During building the object, for `goodbye.sayGoodbye(myName);` statement,  the terminal shows this error: 
[image]

Definition of `sayGoodbye()` function inside `GoodbyeObject` class :

```
void
GoodbyeObject::sayGoodbye(std::string other_name)
{
    DPRINTF(Hello, "Saying goodbye to %s\n", other_name);
    message= " Goodbye" + other_name + "!! ";
    fillBuffer();
}
```

goodbye object is declared as `const GoodbyeObject * goodbye;` and myName is declared as `const std::string myName;` in `class HelloObject` .

I have tried `goodbye->sayGoodbye(myName);` instead of `goodbye.sayGoodbye(myName);` and do not declaring goodbye object as const. this gives error too.
[image] Could you please give me some insight regarding why this error occurs or where I'm making the mistakes?

Comment: Hi there, please don't use screenshots of your terminal, copy and paste text instead. These seem like basic C++ problems, I think you just have to study a bit of C++. Try to make minimal examples outside of gem5 that reproduce the problem. Then if you find it, send a suggestion to Jason Lowe-Power if there is a bug in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with gem5 but from a pure C++ perspective your code has multiple problems.

1. Your object is `const` but your member function isn't. Remove the `const` from the variable declaration (`GoodbyeObject* goodbye`) or add a `const` to the function declaration (`void GoodbyeObject::sayGoodbye(std::string other_name) const`).
2. Since your variable is a pointer, its members are accessed with `->` not with `.`.
3. Your *incomplete type* error indicates that you didn't include the class definition before you use the variable. This happens if you forward declare a class (ex. `class GoodbyeObject;`, note the semicolon at the end) and then try to use it without fully defining it first. Have you included the header in which you define `GoodbyeObject`?